# How to move this structure to the right without using float?

Tags: css

I have this HTML and CSS -

```css
.font-size-add-class {
 background-color: #2f2f2f;
 color: #f9f7f1;
}

.font-sizes {
  text-align: right;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.font-sizes > .small {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.font-sizes > .medium {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.font-sizes > .large {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.font-sizes > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
  border-right: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
}
.font-sizes > div:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
}
```

```html
<div class="font-sizes">
    <div class="small">a</div><!--
 --><div class="medium font-size-add-class">a</div><!--
 --><div class="large">a</div>
</div>
```

If I don't use `table` on the parent and `table-cell` on the child then the `div` blocks will have different sizes due to varying font-size and additionally the fonts won't be horizontally aligned

I want to make the structure exactly like the way it is looking now except that it should be on the right side. How can I do it?

Comment: `.font-sizes { float: right }`?

Comment: You don't read the question properly, do you?

Comment: I did. Used the console to test and it worked.

Comment: There was a reason I specifically asked not to use float due to the HTML following these.

Comment: Oh, it is in question header :D missed that part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of text-align add this:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: 0;
```

```css
.font-size-add-class {
 background-color: #2f2f2f;
 color: #f9f7f1;
}

.font-sizes {
  /*text-align: right;*/
  display: table;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto; /* align table to the right */
  margin-right: 0;
}
.font-sizes > .small {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.font-sizes > .medium {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.font-sizes > .large {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.font-sizes > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
  border-right: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
}
.font-sizes > div:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
}
```

```html
<div class="font-sizes">
    <div class="small">a</div><!--
 --><div class="medium font-size-add-class">a</div><!--
 --><div class="large">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your solution, mister :)

Comment: This is gold! Never used margin property that way +1